Making retrieving data from database faster
last time L had that type of retrieving data:
var users = _context.Users.AsQueryable();


var userDtos = users.Select(user => new UserGetDto
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = user.Name,
    SurName = user.SurName,
    Age = user.Age,
    Faculty = user.Faculty != null
              ? new FacultyOnlyDto
              {
                  Id = user.Faculty.Id,
                  FacultyName = user.Faculty.FacultyName
              }
              : null,
    Courses = user.UsersCourses != null
              ? user.UsersCourses.Where(uc => uc.Course != null).Select(uc => new CourseOnlyDto
              {
                  Id = uc.Course.Id,
                  CourseName = uc.Course.CourseName
              }).ToList()
              : new List<CourseOnlyDto>(),
    Lecturers = user.UsersLecturers != null
                ? user.UsersLecturers.Where(ul => ul.Lecturer != null).Select(ul => new LecturerOnlyDto
                {
                    Id = ul.Lecturer.Id,
                    Name = ul.Lecturer.Name,
                    SurName = ul.Lecturer.SurName,
                    Age = ul.Lecturer.Age
                }).ToList()
                : new List<LecturerOnlyDto>()
}).ToList();

but it was super slow, than I tried to faster it up using that LINQ query:
var users = _context.Users.AsQueryable();
var userLecturers = _context.UsersLecturersJoin.AsQueryable();
var lecturers = _context.Lecturers.AsQueryable();
var userCourses = _context.UsersCoursesJoin.AsQueryable();
var courses = _context.Courses.AsQueryable();
var faculties = _context.Faculty.AsQueryable();

var query = from u in users
            join uc in userCourses on u.Id equals uc.UserId into joinedUserCourses
            from ucs in joinedUserCourses.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ul in userLecturers on u.Id equals ul.UserId into joinedUserLecturers
            from uls in joinedUserLecturers.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join f in faculties on u.FacultyId equals f.Id into joinedFaculties
            from fs in joinedFaculties.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { u, ucs, uls, fs } by new
            {
                u.Id, u.Name, u.SurName, u.Age,
                FacultyId = fs.Id, fs.FacultyName,
                ucs.CourseId,
                uls.LecturerId
            }
            into groupedResult
            select new UserGetDto
            {
                Id = groupedResult.Key.Id,
                Name = groupedResult.Key.Name,
                SurName = groupedResult.Key.SurName,
                Age = groupedResult.Key.Age,
                Faculty = new FacultyOnlyDto
                {
                    Id = groupedResult.Key.FacultyId,
                    FacultyName = groupedResult.Key.FacultyName
                },
                Courses = (from res in groupedResult
                           join c in courses on res.ucs.CourseId equals c.Id into joinedCourses
                           from cs in joinedCourses.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new CourseOnlyDto
                           {
                               Id = cs.Id,
                               CourseName = cs.CourseName
                           }),
                Lecturers = (from res in groupedResult
                             join l in lecturers on res.uls.LecturerId equals l.Id into joinedLecturers
                             from ls in joinedLecturers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new LecturerOnlyDto
                             {
                                 Id = ls.Id,
                                 Name = ls.Name,
                                 SurName = ls.SurName,
                                 Age = ls.Age
                             })
            };
var res = query.ToList();



That last method gives me subqueries in main query and I think that subqueries are not neccessary and it can be simpified, but I don't know how :) Any tips? Should I use dapper to faster it or i don't have to?

faster it up via Stored Procedures. Stored procedures are faster as compared to LINQ queries since they have a predictable execution plan and can take full advantage of SQL features. Hence, when a stored procedure is being executed next time, the database uses the cached execution plan to execute that stored procedure.

@BartMcEndree: Hence, when a stored procedure is being executed next time - the absolutely same is true of any SQL query - in a stored procedure or not. So  if you execute this unwieldy Linq query again - the plan it got the first time will be reused - just like that of a stored procedure ....

Which ORM are you using? Entity Framework? Please add the appropriate tags. The first query looks much better and you should look into the query plan of its generated SQL. The improvement should be found in the database, not in a different LINQ query. BTW, you can remove the nul checks on user.UsersCourses and user.UsersLecturers.

"but it was super slow" - how much data you have in the table? What query is generated? Where the database is located compared to the server running the query?

Despite everything else what was mentioned before you can try couple of more things.

Try split query strategy. If you have small number of courses and lecturers but big number of students - then It can bring some performance improvements. Has to be measured though.
If you are selecting the data just for returning without further modifications - consider to use AsNoTracking method to skip the change tracker.
I don't see the Include methods in your LINQ. Might be that your are using lazy loading approach. If so - you have a N+1 issue here. Investigate the generated SQL.


I have changed important parts of the query. You don't have to check collections for nulls and AsSplitQuery for improving Eager Loading.
var users = _context.Users.AsQueryable();

var userDtos = users.Select(user => new UserGetDto
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        SurName = user.SurName,
        Age = user.Age,
        Faculty = user.Faculty != null
                ? new FacultyOnlyDto
                {
                    Id = user.Faculty.Id,
                    FacultyName = user.Faculty.FacultyName
                }
                : null,
        Courses = user.UsersCourses
                    .Where(uc => uc.Course != null)
                    .Select(uc => new CourseOnlyDto
                    {
                        Id = uc.Course.Id,
                        CourseName = uc.Course.CourseName
                    }).ToList(),
        Lecturers = user.UsersLecturers
                        .Where(ul => ul.Lecturer != null)
                        .Select(ul => new LecturerOnlyDto
                        {
                            Id = ul.Lecturer.Id,
                            Name = ul.Lecturer.Name,
                            SurName = ul.Lecturer.SurName,
                            Age = ul.Lecturer.Age
                        }).ToList()
    })
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToList();


Is it faster than my LINQ query? and can u tell me how

I have mentioned two things which improves your query. But probably AsSpliQuery is really helpful part here Single vs. Split Queries

@NikaKiknadze You're waiting for someone to provide the magic solution. Remember, however, that we can't run your code. You have to do that. You should also answer some comments below your question. We still need to know more than just these two LINQ statements you provided. We assume you're using a fairly recent version of Entity Framework, but we don't know. If you don't know yourself then, frankly, I wonder if you're capable of dealing with answers appropriately.

Despite everything else what was mentioned before you can try couple of more things.

Try split query strategy. If you have small number of courses and lecturers but big number of students - then It can bring some performance improvements. Has to be measured though. Split query is available from EF Core 7 I believe, see if it is applicable for you.
If you are selecting the data just for returning without further modifications - consider to use AsNoTracking method to skip the change tracker.
I don't see the Include methods in your LINQ. Might be that your are using lazy loading approach. If so - you have a N+1 issue here. Investigate the generated SQL.


Since everything has a .Select projection, your points 2 & 3 won't apply.
